# Notice is Firing Twice when Saving User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I save a new user the notice fires twice. Any suggestions on how to get it to fire once? I am also using Sorcery

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
        redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile successfully created.' 
        auto_login(@user)
      else
        render :new 
      end  
  end
```

Comment: I think you have multiple flash blocks in your app which is showing notice twice

Answer (score 1):

As per the code snippet given above, I don't think notice will appear twice. There is nothing wrong in your code. There is one possible chance that in your `application` layout displaying notice is defined once and in your current view template it's defined again. That's why it's showing twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Flash:**

> The flash provides a way to pass temporary objects between actions. Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out.

*A notice can't fire twice according to your code. In your app you somewhere have **this code twice (my guess would be in your layout file and then your view)***

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>
```